# Error [object Object] - Firebase Storage File Upload via File API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-storage

> Note: Running this in codesandbox.io

Trying to upload a file to Firebase Storage, but getting an Error [object Object]. I am successfully able to write things to FireStore and confirmed `selectedFile` is of type file.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase from "./firebase"

function AddImage() {

        // Get a reference to the storage service, which is used to create references in your storage bucket
        var storage = firebase.storage();

        // Create a storage reference from our storage service
        var storageRef = storage.ref();

        var imageRef = storageRef.child('imageLogs/wtfd.png');
        //alert(imageRef);

  const uploadImage = () => {
    alert('In upload image');
    var selectedFile = document.getElementById('image').files[0];
    try {

      alert('In try');
      imageRef.put(selectedFile).then(function (snapshot) {
        setImage('Booyah');
        console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
      });
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(err.message);
        }
  }

  const [uploadedImage, setImage] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" id="image" />
      <br />
      <input type="button" value="Add image" onClick={() => uploadImage()} />
      <br />
      <p>Uploaded Image: {uploadedImage}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddImage;
```

***Update:***

Same error message is received for .getDownloadUrl() on an existing image in Firebase Storage:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase from "./firebase"

function GetImage() {
        var storage = firebase.storage();

        var imageRef = storage.refFromURL('gs://XXXXX-XXXXX.appspot.com/imageLogs/preview.jpg');

  const getDownloadUrl = () => {
    try {
      imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        setImageDownloadUrl(url);
      }
      );

    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(err.message);
        }
  }

  const [imageDownloadUrl, setImageDownloadUrl] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Get Download Url" onClick={() => getDownloadUrl()} />
      <br />
      <p>Image Download Url: {imageDownloadUrl}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GetImage;
```

**firebase.js:**

```
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and
// must be listed before other Firebase SDKs
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

// Add the Firebase services that you want to use
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/storage";

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "ZZZZZZZZ-XXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXX-XXXXXX.XXXX.com",
  databaseURL: "https://XXXXX-XXXXX.XXXX.com",
  projectId: "XXXXXXXXX-XXXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXXXX-XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXX",
  messagingSenderId: "ZZZZZZ",
  appId: "1:XXXX:XXXXXXXXXX",
  measurementId: "G-XXXXX"
};

// Initialize Firebase
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export default firebase;
```

***Error Message with Stack:***

[image]

Comment: It'd probably be very helpful to see what `[object Object]` in your error message actually is. Can you check where it is logged from, and make sure to show the complete message (possibly `JSON.stringify`ing it if needed)?

Comment: Image attached with stack that reports the error. Since it's in a try catch I would think that would capture this error, but it does not, with that being said, I'm not sure where/what to JSON.stringify(). Note: This is is running in CodeSandbox.io

Answer (score 0):

It was a 403 forbidden error due to the firebase storage rules.

It was not captured in the try catch because the authentication was a promise that returned the error after the upload function had already been executed.

Error was captured once brought onto the local machine from CodeSandbox and exception caught in Chrome DevTools console inspeciton. Code Sandbox simply displayed the error messaged Error [object Object].

Upon updating storage rules permitting access, CodeSandox version of repository works as well.